# Using Mathematica to connect to Cloudera Impala

Tags: interoperability, databaselink, databases

I am trying to connect to [Cloudera Impala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudera_Impala) via *Mathematica*, but so far I have not been able to do so. Has anyone ever done it?

I have been able to connect to it via R using the JDBC or ODBC interface and the Cloudera JAR driver.

Comment: You need to elaborate more in your question. Please share the code you are working on. Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). have you look into [`JDBCDrivers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/JDBCDrivers.html) and [Database Connectivity](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DatabaseConnectivity.html)?

Comment: Don't know much about Cloudera. It seems like a Hadoop management system? Mathematica has [HadoopLink](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/31/mathematica-gets-bigdata-with-hadooplink)

Comment: Both thank you for your comments. Unfortunately i can't share any Mathematica code in this case since i do not know how to connect with Mathematica to Impala. If it does help i can share an R example script . I am using R right now as alternative. In R i am using a JDBC driver and the Cloudera JAR. Yes Cloudera is based on Hadoop however the database query i am using is not using directly the Hadoop interface.

Comment: I did spent some additional time on this and i do believe i found a solution. Maybe it will help somebody else. Step 1: load the Cloudera Device Driver (http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/connectors/impala/jdbc/2-5-5.html). Step2: set the Classpath : Needs["JLink`"];
AddToClassPath[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "Impala"}]];     Step 3: open a connection      conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC[
   "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc4.Driver", 
   "jdbc:impala://impalaelb.xyz.com:21050"
   ],
  "Name" -> "manualImpala", "Username" -> ""
  ]          (sorry for the messy edit)